# Trying to implement MVP using Dagger 2 - How can I get a reference to the Activity in the provided presenter

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mvp, dagger-2

I am trying to set up an app with MVP and Dagger,

The **view** is an `Activity` which implements a view interface.

```
public class OverviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OverviewContract.View {

    @Inject OverviewPresenter presenter;

    @BindView(R.id.history_days) ListView HistoryLabels;
    @BindView(R.id.history_events) ListView HistoryEvents;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        DaggerOverviewComponent.create().inject(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void showHistory(List<Exercise> history) {
      // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void updateScoreSlider(float value) {
      // ...
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.add_event_button)
    public void addEvent(View v){
      // ...
    }
}
```

The **presenter** looks like so

```
public class OverviewPresenter implements OverviewContract.Events {

    OverviewContract.View view;

    public OverviewPresenter( OverviewContract.View overviewView ) {
        view = overviewView;

    }

    @Override
    public void loadHistory() {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void addNewEvent() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Where I am having trouble is with the **provider** for the presenter. One of the dependencies of `OverviewPresenter` is the `OverviewActivity`, but how am I supposed to inject the instance of `OverviewActivity` into the `OverviewPresenter` ?

```
@Module
public class PresenterModule {

    @Provides
    static OverviewPresenter provideOverviewPresenter(){
        return new OverviewPresenter(/* pass in the instance of the activity here?? */);
    }
}
```

My **component** looks like

```
@Component(modules = {PresenterModule.class})
public interface OverviewComponent {

    void inject(OverviewActivity overviewActivity);
}
```

Forgive me if this is way off base, I am still trying to wrap my head around dagger.

TLDR:
How can I set this up so that my OverviewActivity can be injected with an OverviewPresenter which itself is injected with the instance of OverviewActivity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- To provide things that dagger can not create itself, you need to use a module.
- To provide your presenter, of which you can just annotate the constructor with `@Inject` you don't need to use a module—and shouldn't.

Since your view implements the view, you can not create the view yourself, nor can dagger. Hence create a module to provide *the view*

```
@Module
public class OverviewModule {

    OverviewView mView;

    OverviewModule(OverviewView view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    @Provides
    static OverviewView provideOverviewView() {
        return mView;
    }
}
```

Then adapt your presenter to use constructor injection

```
public class OverviewPresenter implements OverviewContract.Events {

    OverviewContract.View view;

    @Inject
    public OverviewPresenter( OverviewContract.View overviewView ) {
        view = overviewView;
    }
}
```

Then just add the module to your component and you're done.

```
@Component(modules = {OverviewModule.class})
public interface OverviewComponent {

    void inject(OverviewActivity overviewActivity);
}
```

Now just inject your presenter and you're done (something like this, there could be a typo):

```
DaggerOverviewComponent.builder().overviewModule(new OverviewModule(this)).build()
        .inject(this);
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I'm very happy to have this working

Comment: Does this mean I'll have to create dedicated `@Module`s as well as `@Component`s for each `View` which I need to inject into the Presenter?

Comment: @Daksh in this case, yes. You might be able to come up with more generic solutions, though, which would reuse some classes

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why we shouldn't use module to inject presenter?

Comment: @Reynaldi what modules? Injection always happens with a component, modules are just there to provide additional objects

Answer (score 0):

The thing is maybe you should not use a module for this, since the link between the view and the presenter should depend on the lifecycle, so depending on a module is kind of overkill to me.
Your activity should be injected a presenter, but the activity should call methods like presenter.accept(this) or presenter.takeView(this)....whatever the name when the activity is ok to handle things. Usually it goes like this:
- on Resume -> presenter.takeView(this)
- on Pause -> presenter.dropView();

A very good tutorial about the Mosby framework can be read at 
http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/
it talks a lot about the MVP pattern